# YII2 Access Control With Modules

Tags: yii2, access-control

My access control code is not working on the modules default controller, but on all other pages it is working fine. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

EDIT: What is happening is : ../web/mymodule does not redirect but ../web/mymodule/mycontroller does. Also if o try ../web/mymodule/default it does not work also.

EDIT 2: Solved. The problem was with the `public function beforeAction($action)`

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: What happens? Is there an error? Simply not doing anything?

Comment: Any one can access the page. it does not redirect to login.

Comment: And you are sure that you actually have logged out right? A `@` means: the current user is not a guest. And `guest` means: `\Yii::$app->user->identity === null;`, so not a user with ID = 0

Comment: i went to private navigation and only module default controller can be seen, all other redirect correctly. so i don't understand what you mean @Blizz

Comment: You should share specifictly how you solved the problem, you come here for help to at least you can is provide a answer, this way the community help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't control the action. Try this in `SiteController`:

```
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            ..............
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Still does not work. All other indexes are redirect i just don't understand why the `defaultController index` does not.

Comment: I already found the issue. Was in the `public function beforeAction($action)`. Thank you for the help anyway.